# REST framework's FileField: How can I force using TemporaryUploadedFile

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to extract and process text from a text document uploaded by the user without actually saving the document. I use Django's REST framework and I want this to happen in the serializer.

I get the document from a FileField. Because the text document is likely to be small, it will be wrapped into InMemoryUploadedFile automatically. However, text-extraction modules (e.g. docx2python) need to open files from paths, not from memory.

How can I turn an InMemoryUploadedFile into a TemporaryUploadedFile, so I can get a path to use? Or how do I force a particular field (without changing the app settings) to always wrap a file in TemporaryUploadedFile?

Comment: Probably not a final answer, but as I struggled finding or coming up with any good solution so far, maybe this workaround will help and is worth a comment.
With some help in a [https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/soebxo/rest_frameworks_filefield_how_can_i_force_using/](Reddit thread) I created, I came up with this workaround editing my view:
`def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request = super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
        request.upload_handlers = [TemporaryFileUploadHandler(request=request)]
        return request`